# Atom上からHTMLをChromeで開きたい！

Tags: atom-editor

お世話になります。

Macのデフォルトの機能で.htmlファイルをAtomで開くようにしている状態で、
Atom上からChromeで開きたいのですが、適切なプラグインがみつかりません。

何かいい方法はありませんか？

「open-in-browser」とか
「open-html-in-browser」というやつだと、
Atomで開いてしまいます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[open-in-browser](https://atom.io/packages/open-in-browser) はファイルに紐付けられたデフォルトのアプリでファイルを開くプラグインです。おそらく HTML ファイルに Atom が紐付けられているので、ブラウザではなく Atom が開くのでしょう。したがって、紐付けを変更してよければ、HTML ファイルのデフォルト・アプリをブラウザに設定すれば open-in-browser のままでも使えます。

また、[open-in-browsers](https://atom.io/packages/open-in-browsers) などのプラグインは紐付けられたアプリではなく指定したアプリで開きます。

Answer (score 1):

- [browser-plus](https://atom.io/packages/browser-plus)
- <del>[run-in-browser](https://atom.io/packages/run-in-browser)</del> (リンク切れ)

この２つどうでしょうか
試してないので使えるかわかりませんが(すみません)

以下のブログで紹介されています。

- http://blog.onk164.net/archives/704.html
- http://co.bsnws.net/article/97

Comment: ありがとうございます！試してみます！

Comment: すみませんでした。Stack Overflowは昨日使い始めたばかりで・・

`apm install browser-plus`
をターミナルで実行して
パっけー字をインストール、そして画面で右クリックからの「open browser-plus」ボタンを押します。

Comment: すみません、編集ができなくなってしまって

上の方は、run-in-browserというパッケージをインストールします。

`apm install run-in-browser`だと思います。
ctrl + alt + rで使えます。